# Why I cant login to tfs?

Tags: tfs

I am a member of a tfs profile and an owner of one else.

When I want to login to tfs the following page would be shown and nothing else.

[image: This is the window image]

If the problem is from saved login datas, so how can I completely clear any login data?

How can I get rid of this page and login to tfs normally?

Answer (score 0):

You will always get this page when you log into http://tfs.visualstudio.com. If you want to log directly into the web access for a collection you need to specify http://myaccount.visualstudio.com.

Comment: @MyHinsh I want to login from vs. When the vs opens a window to get my username and password and after getting them it will show another window that you can see in the picture. Then nothing happen and if I close this window I will see that I am not logged in.

Comment: Have you tried clearing all of your internet files and cookies?

Comment: Still not working. Is'nt there any settings for source control to solve it?

Comment: Its not a source control issue. Can you login through the web access?

Comment: Yes I can easily login via web. The problem occur just in loging in with vs.

Comment: Can you click "sign out" and then go to http://live.com and "sign out". Then clear your cookies, and open your credential manager and delete all your liveid saved credentials. then try again

Comment: It did not work. I made a new hotmail account and tried to login but it was imposible...

Comment: What was impossible? ... anyway... it sounds lmike a bigger issue with your account. Can you ask for support on the MSDN forum? That's where the product team hangs out and it sounds like this is specific to your account.